Can't install Cisco Packet Tracer 8.2.2
I am trying to install Cisco Packet Tracer on my computer, but no matter what it won't work. When trying to install the .deb file provided by Cisco it says that
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'packettracer' instead of './CiscoPacketTracer822_amd64_signed.deb'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 packettracer : Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Trying to install libglq-mesa-glx gives the error
Package libgl1-mesa-glx is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libgl1-mesa-glx' has no installation candidate

Does anyone know what I need to do or where I can get the libglg-mesa-glx installer? also, what even is an installation candidate? Is there a way that I can install the windows version, if the linux one is broken?
Sorry if this is a stupid question: I just installed linux two days ago, so I'm still getting used to it.
Versions:
Ubuntu: 24.04.1
GNOME: 46
kernel: Linux 6.8.0-45-generic
Packet tracer installer: 8.2.2

I do see the libgl1-mesa-glx package available for some [older] releases, but you've not told us your release so we can't currently offer much. Given the age of that package; are you using a supported release? as deb packages are built for specific releases & you've not yet told us yours.

sorry I ams using Ubuntu 24.04.1 with GNOME Version 46 and kernel version Linux 6.8.0-45-generic

The error message in your question says packettracer : Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx but it is not installable in Ubuntu 24.04, but you can manually download the libgl1-mesa-glx package from Ubuntu 22.04 and install it in Ubuntu 24.04. Change directories using cd to the directory containing the CiscoPacketTracer822_amd64_signed.deb file that you downloaded and run the following commands.
sudo apt update  
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/m/mesa/libgl1-mesa-glx_22.0.1-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb 
sudo apt install ./libgl1-mesa-glx_22.0.1-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb ./CiscoPacketTracer822_amd64_signed.deb


Thank you, thank you.
So developers have to release specific versions for each version of Ubuntu for it to be downloadable form apt?

A package(s) are updated in Ubuntu when the package maintainer(s) of a package decide that they are ready to be updated. Some packages like web browsers are updated frequently. Other packages can go for four or more Ubuntu releases without being updated to a newer version.

but like if it was available for an older version, why wouldn't it show for my current version of Ubuntu

Canonical recently upgraded the libgl1-mesa-glx package in 24.04. The upgrade was rolled out as a phased update. Now the upgrade to libgl1-mesa-glx has passed beyond phased update status in Ubuntu 24.04.
